# Asymptotics of function of $n^a$, $2^n$ and $\sqrt{n}$, when $n\to\infty$

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

I am having trouble with estimation of the following$$\frac{n^a}{2^{n-\frac{\sqrt n+1}{2}}(1-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt n})^{n-\frac{\sqrt n-1}{2}}}
$$

Where $n \in N$ and $a$ is a real number greater or equal then 2.

Comment: Paula: Did I get the missing right parenthesis in the right place? Also, in the exponenents do you want the $+1$ and $-1$ to go inside the square roots?

Comment: By _estimation_, do you mean the limit of the expression as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: @: Brian Scott, thank you, your corrections are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For every $a$, this is $2^{-n+o(n)}$, hence the limit is zero.

To show this, prove that the logarithm of $n^a$, the logarithm of the remaining power of $2$ and the logarithm of the funny looking power of $1-\frac1{2\sqrt{n}}$ in the denominator, are all $o(n)$.